# Delete an entry from array in C

Tags: c

I am looking for a way to delete an entry from an array in C. Also delete an entry in a structure.

I am pretty new to C, any idea how to do it?

UPDATE:

Found a code that is supposed to delete an entry from a structure:

```
void removeEntry(student *st, int *nr, char nu[50])
{
    int k=0,i,j;
    for(i=0;i<*nr;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp((st+i)->name,nu)==0)
        {
            k++;
            for(j=i;j<(*nr-k);j++)
            {
                *(st+j)=st[j+1];
            }
        }
    }

    *nr=*nr-k;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider reading a good book about programming in C?

Comment: You can't delete an entry from a structure. From an array you simply have to copy that part of the array that is after the item to be deleted, into its new location.

Comment: This is almost a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838835/how-to-delete-structure-entries-in-c), so you might look there for a little insight into your problem.

Comment: `memmove`. But what is "delete an entry in a structure"?

Comment: What do you mean, not a real question? I was half way through answering this when it got closed. If I can answer it, it must be a real question. If you don't understand the question, post comments to help clarify what it is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I updated with a code that is supposed to delete from a structure.

Comment: This doesn't do that. It operates on arrays of structs. Really, you cannot delete a field from a struct.

Comment: There is a serious nomenclature matter here. When a c programer hears or reads "structure" without a modifier  she thinks `struct ... { ...}`. You *don't* remove members of `struct`s, though you *could* release memory pointed to by one. On the other hand you may mean a node in a more complex "data structure" such as a linked list, a tree, etc. Those can be removed (in some cases depending on what data structure you mean). So we have at least three possible means here (one nonsensical and two manageable). Please be specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete an entry in a dynamically allocated array (replace `T` by the actual type stored in the array):

```
// delete element i in array a of size n
T *delete(T *a, size_t n, size_t i)
{
    memmove(&(a[i]), &(a[i+1]), n - i - 1);
    return realloc(a, sizeof(T) * (n - 1));
}
```

If order doesn't matter, then replace the `memmove` with `t[i] = t[n-1];`

There's no way to remove a member from a `struct`.

Comment: Well, this is the fancy and efficient way ;)

Comment: Guy's just starting. Took me 1/2 a day to figure out waht you were doing. :(

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: the OP is asking something that is simply difficult in C.

Comment: It may be more efficient not to do the realloc

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: true. It may also be more efficient to actually do it, in the long run. I just put it in for completeness.

Comment: @larsmans is there any library I should include? Otherwise it says identifier "memmove" is undefined. Same for realloc.

Comment: @Andrew: `memmove` is in `<string.h>`. `realloc` is in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: It's probably most efficient to do it when the array length is less than some % of the capacity, but that's rather advanced for this question.

Comment: @larsmans memmove(&(t[i]), &(t[i+1]), n - i - 1); instead of t, isn't there a?

Comment: what is the complexity of this function ?

Answer (score 1):

Just move all entries after the entry to delete to their preceding position, one after another. When you're using a dynamic array you may also want to perform a `realloc` for resizing the array.